# How do I get PyDev to show pylint errors in the editor?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pylint

I have the latest PyDev (2.8.2) and pylint (1.0.0) installed.  I am trying to get pylint errors and warnings to show up in the PyDev editor. It seems to do nothing when I enable it.  When I set it to redirect output to the console, it seems to be working correctly (see screenshot).

How can I get it working?

[image: Console output]

Comment: Do you see Pylint errors and warnings in your Problems tab? They should also show up there, [like this](http://pydev.org/images/codeanalysis/code_analysis_problems.png).

Comment: @nofinator No, I don't.  I have a bunch of errors from PyDev itself, but none specific to Pylint.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your problems tab please?

Comment: @ifx [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/xFzMObm.png)

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few reasons why pylint won't work in PyDev.

### Make sure PyLint is configured

The options can be found at `window` -> `preferences` -> `pydev` -> `pylint`.

Check `use pylint?`

For `Location of pylint.py (lint.py):` click the browse button and select the file.  For me on Debian GNU/Linux it's at `/usr/share/pyshared/pylint/lint.py`.  If you're on another distribution your package manage should have a way to show you the files that were installed with the pylint package.  Search it via grep for `lint.py`.

If all of that is good, verify that `FATAL`, `ERRORS`, `WARNINGS`, `CONVENTIONS`, and `REFACTOR` severities are not set to ignore.

Click `OK`.

Give it a minute as PyDev may take a moment to get the pylint stuff figured out.  Then purposely introduce a pylint warning.  Something like an easy `foo.bar()` when `foo` isn't defined should create a error that will show up after saving the file.

### Make sure you're source files are on the PYTHONPATH

Under `Project` -> `Properties` -> `PyDev - PYTHONPATH` look at the `Source Folders` tab, if you don't have anything in the box, that's a problem.  Add your source directory to it via the `Add Source Folder` button.  If you're code is in the root of the project, just select the project directory.  If it's under another folder, select that.

**Note**: You only need to select the root of the code, not every folder in the project.

### Check your extensions

Make sure the file you're testing against has a .py extension.  PyDev will not call pylint for any file that does not have a .py extension.  So if you have a calling/setup script that calls into the rest of your application that doesn't have a .py extension, it won't check it.

Comment: I've checked all that and it seems to be configured correctly.  foo.bar() does show up as an error, but PyDev does that anyway, without PyLint enabled.

Comment: If you hover over the red x do you see `Undefined variable: foo`, `ID:E0602 Undefined variable'foo'`, or both?  If it's one of the last two, pylint is working.

Comment: I just see the regular PyDev message, "Undefined variable: foo"

Comment: And you're certain you have pylint installed?  It is not included in python proper nor pydev and must be installed separately.

Comment: Yes, hence it working when I make PyDev output it to the console

Comment: I just looked again at how you're calling pylint.  Under `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `PyDev` -> `Interpreter - Python` does the location of the python interpreter match /ops/apps/Python2.7.3?  Also, what was the path that you found lint.py in?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure that you have autobuild turned on for pylint to work after changes without additional actions.
Then check that you don't have more changes than it's configured in option that specifies the maximum delta to use pylint on.
And of course enable pylint in problem filters if you haven't already.
Think it must help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which settings to check?  I am pretty sure autobuild is already enabled since I get regular PyDev errors and warnings pretty much right away when I write something invalid. Yes, PyLint is already enabled in the problems filters.

Answer (score 1):

Your console output is showing binary characters, it could be a file encoding problem. May be your *.py have DOS line endings, if so convert them (seems your box is a Linux one)

```
dos2unix <your files>
```

You could also try on the command line the command in the first line of your console. This is how my console looks like

```
PyLint: Executing command line: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint-1.0.0-py2.7.egg /pylint/lint.py --rcfile=$HOME/.pylintrc test.py
PyLint: The stdout of the command line is: ************* Module updateProgress
C: 14, 0: Line too long (89/80) (line-too-long)
C: 26, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
C: 40, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
C: 42, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
```

Comment: Those "binary characters" are ANSI control sequences and expected.